# Is Math.Abs(a-b) safe?

Tags: c#, integer-overflow

I am using Math.Abs(a-b) to determine the difference between 2 numbers.
Is this a safe way to do this or can I get unexpected result due to Underflow?

(I want to know in General for all the type overloads of Math.Abs)

Comment: You should take into account that `Math.Abs(a-b)` will perform `a-b` and *then* pass the result to `Math.Abs`. The fact that you are passing `a-b` to `Math.Abs` is irrelevant

Comment: `Math.Abs(int.MaxValue - int.MinValue)`

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: What's "unexpected"? `Math.Abs((int.MinValue + 1) - 1)` does not overflow at compile time, but the result of the `Abs` is unrepresentable, so it still won't work.

Comment: For `Decimal`, `Double` and `Single`, `Abs` is nothing special since all those types use sign bits that can simply be flipped. The integer types use two's complement, so all calls where `a - b` results in the lowest representable value will fail. This is not "underflow", however, nor is it clear that it's the problem you're looking for.

Comment: @fubo: The simplest case for Math.Abs to generate an exception for a valid value is _Math.Abs(int.MinValue);_

Comment: @fubo My point being any pair of values subtracted that results in int.MinValue will cause an exception in Math.Abs, but not the calculation itself.